# Trying to retrive data from database, get data from object to string.

Tags: java, android, database, parse-platform

I am trying to retrive an object from mine database, I am using Parse.com for this. I outputs got the object so I supposed it's saved somewhere? 
How do i get the message from the object to a string? 
Thanks!

```
               ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Messages");

    query.whereEqualTo("Number", nruser);
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (object == null) {
                Log.d("Object", "The getFirst request failed.");

            } else {
                Log.d("Object", "Retrieved the object.");
                Toast.makeText(DrivingUser.this, "Got the object.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood right what you want to do, then you need to use :

```
String message = parseObject.getString(Constants.MESSAGE); //Constans.MESSAGE is column name of message in database ("Messages")
```